# Java key release event from STDIN in terminal raw mode

Tags: java, unix, terminal, stdin

I'm trying to write a console game using java, and when you hold down a key, I want it to move your character constantly.

This means I need key press and key release events, because there is a delay when you hold down a key before it starts typing that same letter over and over.

I've already put the terminal into raw mode using stty, but I don't seem to be getting key release events.

This answer seems to indicate that I can indeed get those events from STDIN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598436/2404047

What I actually receive when in raw mode is a single byte for most keys, but in some cases, like the arrow keys, I get multiple bytes.

Is there a way I can get key press and release events through STDIN, or is a console game like this simply not doable?

Answer (score 1):

This is your missunderstanding. You cannot get events from console using pure java.

Possible solutions are:

1. Get events using native utility, redirect them to file/pipe and read them into java code from that file
2. Use JNI/JNA directly
3. Use library that already wraps JNI and expose Java API for this purpose. Take a look on [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/) that provides you API you need and even much more.

Comment: So, if I was to read STDIN in C, I could receive key events? Or would I need to get key events via some other method? (including both press and release events)