# Key pressed and key released interrupts in C

Tags: keyboard, c, interrupt, events

Is there a way to catch the **KEY PRESSED** and **KEY RELEASED** events in `while (1)` loop in simple C program on Linux running from a terminal window.

`kbhit()` will return `true` if a key was pressed, `getch()` returns the character that was pressed.

How do I catch the RELEASE event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this in a portable manner.  Terminals (and emulators of those such as [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html)) give you only the key that was pressed, not the release events.  Graphical user interfaces often provide the ability to receive separate press- and release-events.

Terminal emulators running in a graphical environment compose those events into individual characters.  As read in the graphical environment, those are *key symbols*, which may contain *characters*. In addition to the press- and release-events for the key events themselves, you can have *modifiers* such as shift-, control- and meta-modifiers which are separate events.  If you run [`xev`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html), you can see these separate events.

After composing these events into a character, the terminal emulator may send it to your application as a series of data bytes, e.g., in UTF-8 encoding.  When you use [`getch()`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html), the ncurses library reads those bytes, and puts it together again into a character.  In between those two (the terminal emulator and application) are the pseudo-terminal and *its* translation, which both terminal emulator and application must manipulate.

If you are **not** running in a graphical environment, there are (not always) other ways than graphical applications such as `xev` which can read directly the key press/release events.  The Linux console supports that.  See for example the links cited in *[Receiving key press and key release events in Linux terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1598436/4518274)*

Comment: Couldn't `XISelectEvents()` be used on `$WINDOWID` (for X11 emulators)? Like `xinput test-xi2 --root` does on the root window?

Comment: You could write a graphical application, certainly.

Comment: My question was more about whether the XISelectEvents() API could work at querying the X events received by an arbitrary target window. From a quick test (but possibly not conclusive), it doesn't look like it works for any Window but the root window.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with `xterm` and the `openbox` window manager:

```
xinput test-xi2 --root |
  awk -v id="$(
     xwininfo -children -id "$WINDOWID" |
       awk '$1 == "Parent" {print $4}'
     )" '
  $1 == "EVENT"{e = $NF}
  $1 == "detail:" {k = $2}
  $6 == "child" && $7 == id && e ~ /Key/ {print e, k}'
```

Outputs something like:

```
(KeyRelease) 36
(KeyPress) 38
a(KeyRelease) 38
s(KeyPress) 39
d(KeyPress) 40
(KeyRelease) 39
(KeyRelease) 40
```

(those `a`, `s`, `d` are the local echo for the characters that `xterm` wrote to the master side of the pseudo-terminal upon handling those KeyPress events and are not part of the output).

`xinput test-xi2 --root` will report every X Window event for the current `$DISPLAY` including but not limited to keypress and keyrelease events in a format similar to:

```
EVENT type 2 (KeyPress)
    device: 14 (14)
    detail: 54
    flags:
    root: 795.06/645.66
    event: 795.06/645.66
    buttons:
    modifiers: locked 0 latched 0 base 0x4 effective: 0x4
    group: locked 0 latched 0 base 0 effective: 0
    valuators:
    windows: root 0x252 event 0x252 child 0x1c0015b
```

From my limited testing, I find that the `child` field in there seems to match the id of the parent of the terminal emulator main window (which most terminal emulators make available in the `$WINDOWID` environment variable) which receives those events. I suspect that window id is somewhat belongs to the window manager.

So, here, we retrieve that id from the `xwininfo -children` command output, and use that to filter the events reported by `xinput`.

To translate those key codes to key labels, check [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129171).

Now, you'll want to check the source code of `xinput` or play with `ltrace` (if on Linux) to do the same thing directly in C without the help of those utilities.